# shrink width of select, multiple box

Tags: html, css

One of the items in the multiple select box is much longer than the others, is there a way to hack it to make the width of it smaller

```
<select size="1">
<option>item</option>
<option>item</option>
<option>item is really long</option>
<option>item</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with CSS, either in-line style or using a class.

With in-line style:

```
<select style="width: 50px;">
 <option>item</option>
 <option>item</option>
 <option>item is really long</option>
 <option>item</option>
</select>
```

Using a class:

```
<select class="narrow">
 <option>item</option>
 <option>item</option>
 <option>item is really long</option>
 <option>item</option>
</select>
```

And in your CSS file or embedded stylesheet:

```
.narrow {
 width: 50px;
}
```

Of course, change 50px to whatever width you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the width using CSS. If you add a class to the select tag, for instance 'foo', you can then add css:

```
select.foo {
   width: 200px;
}
```

If you want to can use an inline style (not recommended though):

```
<select style="width: 200px";>
  <option>...
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works in FireFox but not in IE :

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
  OPTION.shorter{ font-size:8px;}
</STYLE>

<select size="1">
<option>item</option>
<option>item</option>
<option class="shorter">item is really long</option>
<option>item</option>
</select>
```